# Keep getting error#1502 for this loop in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, flash, if-statement, while-loop

It's supposed to be for a rhythm game, where while the mc is on the stage, the boolean keeps switching back and forth from true to flase and you have to catch it at the right time. But I keep getting an error...

```
while (theBeat)
{
  if (theBeat.currentFrame < 5)
    {
    onBeat = true
    trace(onBeat)
    }

  if (theBeat.currentFrame > 5)
    {
    onBeat = false
    trace(onBeat)
    }
}
```

Gives me:

> **1502**  A script has executed for longer than 15 seconds.

Comment: Shot in the dark: your while loop never stops, the ui thread gets blocked for longer than 15 seconds, bam error 1502 alias "execution time error". Try rewriting your code with an ENTER_FRAME handler instead.

Comment: So I have to right an ENTER_FRAME function every time I want the Boolean to switch? That'd be a pain.

Comment: @Galbert, No ENTER_Frame replaces the While loop. Make an enter frame listener and put the two IF statements in there (best remove traces cos enter Frame runs every per FPS of your SWF and will slow the IDE to print out all the results, maybe have a graphic that changes color / visibilty or whatever as visual hint for false/true )

Comment: You cannot control an app behavior using a while loop. The app view will never update while a while loop is running. Learn about thread execution in AS3.

Comment: `while (theBeat)` is an endless loop if you never set `theBeat` to `null` inside the loop. What is `theBeat` and how is `onBeat` used? Show the variable declarations.

Answer (score 1):

`while (theBeat)` is an endless loop, because `theBeat` is never set to `null` from inside the loop. Endless loops freeze the Flash Player. Like DodgerThud and VC.One already mentioned in the comments you need to evaluate the condition over time, for example with `ENTER_FRAME` or a `Timer`, not in a single loop.

Example:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

function enterFrame(e:Event):void {
    if (theBeat) {
        if (theBeat.currentFrame < 5) {
            onBeat = true;
        }
        if (theBeat.currentFrame > 5) {
            onBeat = false;
        }
        trace("onBeat:", onBeat);
    }
}
```

And when things stop just remove the handler:

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
```

---

You can use a `Timer` to evaluate once per second like this:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.start();
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);

function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {
    if (theBeat) {
        if (theBeat.currentFrame < 5) {
            onBeat = true;
        }
        if (theBeat.currentFrame > 5) {
            onBeat = false;
        }
        trace("onBeat:", onBeat);
        if (onBeat == true && spaceDown == true) {
            points++;
            trace("points:", points);
        }
    }
}
```

And to stop the timer:

```
timer.stop();
```

Comment: But I don't want it to stop. I want it to keep looping and switching the boolean on and off to the beat of the song. Would I just have to copy/paste the same function for every beat of the song?

Comment: You *do* want it to complete the loop, unless you *want* to freeze the Flash Player indefinitely and crash your whole SWF. ;) The `ENTER_FRAME` will continue dispatching indefinitely, executing the function at your frame rate (ex 30 times each second), until you remove it.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Thank you! So the only way to make it execute once per loop would be to make my frame rate 1fps?

Comment: "execute once per loop" -- you mean "execute once per second"? If you want it to execute at a different rate than your frame rate you should use a `Timer`. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: because I'm doing a point system, where if you tap the spacebar when onBeat == true, you get a point. But with this function it gives you points for every frame you held it when onBeat was true, not just one.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. I'll add an example using `Timer`.

Comment: Ok. If I understand what you're going for you need to put the `if onBeat points++` code inside your event handler. Check my example.

Comment: I think the timer is the best option. Thanks again. Do you think there would be a way for it to allow me to get a point on any of the 5 frames, but only once per execution of the function?

Comment: You are missing the core problem here Aaron, the OP he's trying to control an entire app with a while loop thinking that the app can simply run while the while loop controls it. There's a deep misunderstanding from the OP that urgently needs to be addressed or else all solution you might throw at him will likely be misunderstood. It's clear that the OP dismissed my comment because of his deep misunderstanding on single threading. The OP still thinks a while loop can be used to control his app and will still likely fail in his attempts until he understands it.

Comment: My code doesn't even have a while loop anymore, but ok.

Comment: @BotMaster Yeah, you're right about some things. I tried to explain the "infinite loop" bit in simple terms but I'm not sure it conveyed.

Comment: @Galbert I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "a point on any of the 5 frames", but this is a separate question.